# jquery animate a div and when is finish, animate the second div inside the first

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

i have for example a header (140px height) on the web with 5 "li" content. The first 3 of this (A,B,C) open a subheader (50px height) when ".mouseover", the others 2 (D,E) close all to the begining.

```
jq(document).ready(function(){
        jq("#A a,#B a,#C a").mouseover(function(){
            jq("#subheader").animate({top:"140px"},"normal");
        });

        jq("#D a,#E a").mouseover(function(){
            jq("#subheader").animate({top:"91px"},"normal");
        });
    });
```

Until here all is ok, now comes the problem. Depend of which A, B or C is hovered has to do diferent things with the subheader, just at the end of the animation. (open .smenus inside subheader)

```
        jq("#A a").mouseover(function(){
            jq(".smenu1").slideDown("slow");
            jq(".smenu1 ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow");
            jq(".smenu1 li").animate({padding:"0 30px 0"},"slow");

        });
        jq("#B a").mouseover(function(){
            jq(".smenu2").slideDown("slow");
            jq(".smenu2 ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow");
            jq(".smenu2 li").animate({padding:"0 30px 0"},"slow");

        });
        jq("#C a").mouseover(function(){
            jq(".smenu3").slideDown("slow");
            jq(".smenu3 ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow");
            jq(".smenu3 li").animate({padding:"0 30px 0"},"slow");

        });
```

This doesn't work i think because it start loading before finishing the opening of the suheader. so i have to do this animation when the opening is finished.

PD: And now another thing, when for example #A is hovered, and then #B, it has to stop the animation (if is not finished, or just callback), remove others submenus (in this case .smenu1) and replace it whith theirs submenu (in this case .smenu2). #D and #E has to do the same, putting everything back to the begining.

EDITED:

thanks to Simon, I have more or less this: http://jsfiddle.net/PAXqB/4/

the last implementation is to make it with .click() and not with .mouseover() having this 3 cases:

- case 1: Same than mouseover, all opened.
- case 2: Click again the same Main, all have to close like my example.
- case 3: Click on an other Main, close submenu, not suheader, and open the new submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say I had to read your question multiple times and I'm not yet sure if I understood you right, but is this what you wanted to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/PAXqB/

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('ul.main > li').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
        var t = $(this), i = t.index(), sub = t.find('.sub');
        if(i < 3)
            switch(e.type) {
                case 'mouseover':
                    sub.stop(true).slideDown( function() {
                        $(this)
                            .stop(true)
                            .animate({ margin:"20px 0 0" })
                            .find('li')
                            .stop(true)
                            .animate({ padding:"0 10px 0" });
                    });
                    break;
                case 'mouseout':
                    sub.stop(true).slideUp('fast', function() {
                        $(this)
                            .removeAttr('style')
                            .find('li')
                            .removeAttr('style');
                    });
                    break;
            }
    });
});
```

I slightly adjusted the animate-to style so it looks a bit smoother on my jsfiddle, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: yeah, is more or less the same that your code, the thing is that the header Main, is a diferent div with no Submenu than the div subheader where is an other menu, that i called submenu. ill change ir code in a moment and si if works

Comment: Thats it, I changed it in this: http://jsfiddle.net/PAXqB/3/ it works allmost fine, there are some errors, but is relationed with mouseover. Now if u could still help i have to modify it to ".click" there are 3 cases: -case 1: Same than mouseover, all opened. -case 2:I click again the same Main, all have to close like my example. -case 3: i click on an other Main, close submenu, not suheader, and open the new submenu. THX a lot (this modifycation is for Tablets)

Comment: sorry had not much time the last few days, but I try to fix that fiddle during the weekend. greets

Comment: I made a new [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774129/jquery-animate-a-div-and-when-is-finish-animate-the-second-div-inside-the-first/9843900#9843900) for the changes because it's new functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) has a complete callback option :

```
jq(".smenu2 ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow", function() {
   // code here is executed after this animation is complete
});
```

Use [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/), something like :

```
jq(".smenu2").slideDown("slow");     
jq(".smenu2").queue(function () {
  jq(".smenu2 ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow");
  jq(this).dequeue();
});
jq(".smenu2 li").animate({padding:"0 30px 0"},"slow");
```

this simple queues up your animation requests and executes in order

Comment: so i make animate to bring down the subheader, and then i make if and elseif depends of wich A, B or C is choosen? all in callback?. How can i reverse exacly back when i go to other letter, or D and E that restore all to the begining, including sliding up the subheading.

Comment: @IgnacioBustos my answer was to give you ideas on how to stop the animations happening at the same time - its not a final solution ... i recommend you create queues of animations and execute them when required.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend tidying up your code for readability and making it easier to work with. Example:

```
$("#A a, #B a, #C a").on('mouseover', function(){
            $menu = $(this).find(".menu");
            $menu.slideDown("slow");
            $menu.find("ul").animate({margin:"0px auto"},"slow");
            $menu.find("li").animate({padding:"0 30px 0"},"slow");
        }).on('mouseout', function(){
            $(this).find(".menu").stop(true, true);
});
```

Not fully tested, but this should be on the right lines in terms of getting your code working - the .stop() method being the second part of your answer.

Comment: Instead of the .stop, I'd recommend ManseUK's answer for queuing. Good suggestion.

Comment: the ".menu" (in my case .smenuX) is a menu inside the div of subheader, totally outside the header wheres is A, B and C, i think find() will not find it. all of this could be good for the submenus, but it still making problem with the openings and closing of the subheader, maybe the queue is the solution

Comment: Can you not add a class called "menu" to all of the sub items, or "menuInternal" etc? Some class that is similar on all sub-items, rather than differently named classes. Then you could use this approach easily.

Answer (score 0):

Sooo this would be my best solution so far for a tablet: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PAXqB/15/)
I'm working on a version where it acts exactly as you wanted (container just slides down/up if nothing was visible or the clicked item was active), but have some trouble with the animations atm.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var active = 'active';

    $('ul.main > li').bind('click', function() {

        var t = $(this),
            i = t.index(),
            c = $('.sub-container'),
            sub = $( $('.sub').get(i) ),
            isActive = t.hasClass(active),
            li = sub.find('li'),
            liCount = li.length;

        c.slideUp('fast', function() {
            c.find('*').removeAttr('style');
            t.siblings().removeClass(active);
            if(i < 3) {
                if(isActive) t.removeClass(active);
                else {
                    t.addClass(active);
                    c.slideDown( function() {
                        sub.slideDown( function() {
                            li.animate({
                                width: (100 / liCount) + '%'
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```